# Dialogflow has stooped working in Actions on Google

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I noticed today, after accessing my application that DF is no longer working in google assistant.

Every parameter I try to send to the bot(fulfillment) is triggering the fallback Intent...  This behavior was not was not happening at least during the last four months, and suddenly today.....

Is anybody facing the same/similar problem? Any news on changes in google services?

Thanks,

_DM

Comment: While there have been some issues between Dialogflow and Actions recently, this sounds like an odd one, and I haven't seen similar. Updating your questions with concrete examples, screen shots of the Intents, or anything else may help us help you diagnose it further.

Comment: Hi Prisoner, thanks for your reply. By opening a issue at issuetracker today, I found out that everybody using DF + AoG is facing the same problem. Hope they fix that ASAP, as for now I can say theres no stable integration between platforms. _DM

Comment: What is the link to the issue that was opened?

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/165676621

Comment: The Dialogflow issue has  been resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it´s global!
I´ve sent a support ticket to Dialogflow team as well.

Checking the payloads locally, it´s simply unstable, sometimes the session are kept sometimes not…

I noticed that yesterday in the afternoon! Let´s wait for the fixing...

Best!
Rubini